# R: optimize finding max values of function on a data frame and then trim the rest

Tags: r

First of all my data comes from Temperature.xls which can be downloaded from this link: [RBook](http://highstat.com/Book3/RBook.zip)

My code is this:

```r
temp = read.table("Temperature.txt", header = TRUE)
length(unique(temp$Year)) # number of unique values in the Year vector.
res = ddply(temp, c("Year","Month"), summarise, Mean = mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE))
res1 = ddply(temp, .(Year,Month), summarise,
    SD = sd(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
    N = sum(!is.na(Temperature))
         )
# ordering res1 by sd and year:
res1 = res1[order(res1$Year,res1$SD),];
# finding maximum of SD in res1 by year and displaying just them in a separate data frame
res1_maxsd = ddply(res1, .(Year), summarise, MaxSD = max(SD, na.rm = TRUE)) # find the maxSD in each Year
res1_max = merge(res1_maxsd,res1, all = FALSE) # merge it with the original to see other variables at the max's rows
res1_m = res1_max[res1_max$MaxSD==res1_max$SD,] # find which rows are the ones corresponding to the max value
res1_mm = res1_m[complete.cases(res1_m),] # trim all others (which are NA's)
```

I know that I can cut the 4 last lines to less lines. Can I somehow execute the last 2 lines in one command? I have stumbled across:

```r
res1_m = res1_max[complete.cases(res1_max$MaxSD==res1_max$SD),]
```

But this does not give me what I want which is eventually a smaller data frame only with the rows (with all the variables) that contain the maxSD.

Comment: Are you trying to find which year has the largest temperature variation and filter the data by that year?

Comment: yes, only by month instead of year. So I'll get one row per year with the max variation month in it...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fixing the last 2 lines why not start with res1? Reversing the order of SD and taking the first row per year gives you an equivalent final data set...

```
res1 <- res1[order(res1$Year,-res1$SD),]
res_final <- res1[!duplicated(res1$Year),]
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets the job done but I wonder if there is some other more general way, because this method relies on the fact that `!duplicated` will consider only the first occurrence of each year...

Answer (score 0):

The last four lines can be cut down if you use `dplyr` package. Since you want to keep some information from original data set, you probably don't want to use summarise because it only returns summarized information and you have to merge with original dataset, so `mutate` and `filter` would be a better choice:

```
library(dplyr)
res1_mm1 <- res1 %>% group_by(Year) %>% filter(SD == max(SD, na.rm = T))
```

You can also use a `mutate` function to create the new column `MaxSD` which is the same as `SD` in the result data frame for your case:

```
res1_mm1 <- res1 %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(MaxSD = max(SD, na.rm = T)) %>% 
            filter(SD == MaxSD)
```